# Start, pause and restart a timer in Unity C# - Only decrease timer inside trigger and reset when outside trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I need it to do.

Make a timer only decrease while staying in the trigger and reset when outside the trigger.

When timer1 = 0, pause the countdown timer and set teleport to 0

When timer1 = 1, Set the timer to 8 seconds and start counting down, IF 
timercountdown = 0, set teleport to 1 and set Timer1 to 0. (TO reset the timer)

This isnt working properly and Im really not sure why.

The timer gets locked at 8 and doesnt start decreasing when the Timer1 value equals 1.

Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProximityTeleport : MonoBehaviour {
    public float time;
    public int timer1 = 0;
    public int teleport = 0;
    public float timecountdown;   

    void Start () {
    }
    void Update () {

    if (timer1 == 0);
    {
        teleport = 0;
    }

    if (timer1 == 1);
    {
        timecountdown -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timecountdown <= 0.0f);
        {
            teleport = 1;
            timer1 = 0;
        }

    }
}
    void OnTriggerEnter() {
        timecountdown = 8f;
        timer1 = 1;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit() {
        timer1 = 0; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really want to help you but I don't know what you want to do exactly:

You say:

> Make a timer only decrease while staying in the trigger and reset when
>   outside the trigger. When timer1 = 0, pause the countdown timer and
>   set teleport to 0 When timer1 = 1, Set the timer to 8 seconds and
>   start counting down, IF timercountdown = 0, set teleport to 1 and set
>   Timer1 to 0. (TO reset the timer)

What I understand:

On entering the trigger:

- start or continue decreasing countdowntimer
- decrease countdowntimer while staying in trigger

On leaving trigger:

- pause decreasing, but do not reset
- set teleport to 0

If countdowntimer is below zero:

- set teleport to 1
- reset countdowntimer to 8 seconds
- continue decreasing?

Are there other rules for the teleport? 
You say if countdowntimer is zero you want to reset everthing. The teleport, too?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProximityTeleport : MonoBehaviour {
    public float time;
    //public int timer1 = 0;
    public bool triggerActive = false;
    public int teleport = 0;
    public float timecountdown;   

    void Start () {
        timecountdown = 8.0f;
    }
    void Update () {
        if (triggerActive)
        {
            timecountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timecountdown <= 0.0f)
            {
                timecountdown = 8.0f;
                teleport = 1;

                // player has to re-enter the trigger:
                triggerActive = false;
            }

        } else {
            teleport = 0;
            timecountdown = 8.0f;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter() {
        triggerActive = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit() {
        triggerActive = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: On leaving trigger:

reset timer

Comment: Reset everything when it reaches 0 yep

Comment: Ok I changed the code to a complete reset. Player has to re-enter the trigger to start a new countdown.

Comment: `if (triggerActive);` remove `;`

Comment: The teleport activates straight away when trigger active is true, instead of waiting 8 seconds, It seems like it doesnt start the time.delta countdown. TImecountdown is stuck on 8 seconds, but the teleport still becomes 1

Comment: I made an edit. I tested it now on my machine. It's working. Sorry for the miss-spelling. I was using my phone...

Comment: I moved teleport = 0; from the else statement to the OnTriggerExit()  and It works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think it's some kind of logically problem. You say:

> When timer1 = 0, pause the countdown timer and set teleport to 0

but you do:

```
    if (timer1 == 0);
    {
        timecountdown += Time.deltaTime;
        teleport = 0;
    }
```

And there is another problem: as long as `timer1` = 1 you always set `timecountdown = 8f;` here:

```
    if (timer1 == 1);
    {
        timecountdown = 8f;
        timecountdown -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timecountdown <= 0);
        {
            teleport = 1;
            timer1 = 0;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: according to your comments I think I know what you want to do:
You only want to decrease while staying in the trigger?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProximityTeleport : MonoBehaviour {
    public float time;
    public int timer1 = 0;
    public int teleport = 0;
    public float timecountdown;   

    void Start () {
        timecountdown = 8f;
    }
    void Update () {

        if (timer1 == 0);
        {
            teleport = 0;
        }

        if (timer1 == 1);
        {
            timecountdown -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (timecountdown <= 0.0f);
            {
                teleport = 1;
                timer1 = 0;
                timecountdown = 8f;
            }

        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter() {
        //timecountdown = 8f;
        timer1 = 1;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit() {
        timer1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that "timecountdown += Time.deltaTime;" paused my deltatime countdown

Comment: Iv changed the location of timecountdown = 8f from the if statement to void OnTriggerExit()

Comment: Ok the changes look good in your edit. You can remove `timecountdown += Time.deltaTime;` and change `if (timecountdown <= 0);` to `if (timecountdown <= 0.0f);`

Comment: The timer gets locked at 8, it doesnt decrease when Timer1 equals 1

Comment: While `timer1 == 1` your `timecountdown` should decrease... Does `timer1` keep the value `1` ? Or is `OnTriggerExit` called right after `OnTriggerEnter` ? Perhaps you can add some `Debug.Log()` to these functions and share the log?

Comment: As soon as timer1 == 1,  timecountdown becomes 8, When timer1 changes to 0, timercountdown stays at 8

Comment: Yes because there is no decreasing if `timer1 == 0` ! If you want to decrease always to `0` remove the `OnTriggerExit` function!

Comment: but you're not pausing countdown when timer1 == 0, no? You're increasing it

Comment: I only want to decrease the timer when OnTriggerEnter() is on.

Comment: When OnTriggerExit activates, It should just stop the timer and set teleport to 0

Comment: Set `timecountdown = 8f;` in `Start()`

Comment: timer1 stays as 0, teleport becomes 1. I have no idea why